# Zend Framework asking for view script despite setNoRender

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've made an API controller with some actions to spit out JSON for my app and I've turned off the layout and view renderer in its `init()` method so I've got no view scripts for this controller.

I'm trying to use my `apiController::treeAction` elsewhere in the app via an `actionHelper` to output some JSON inline. I can access the action directly via `/api/tree/id/1` which shows me the JSON data. But when I try and fetch from another controller with

```
$this->view->action('tree', 'api', null, array('id'=>$id))
```

I get an exception

```
Message: script 'api/tree.phtml' not found in path ([...]\application\views\scripts\)
```

It's right, that file doesn't exist, but I don't need it to. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the viewRenderer and the layout right at the end of the action. Disabling it in the init should work, so if it works when it's at the end of the action something is wrong elsewhere.

Comment: I wasn't able to resolve this issue. In the end I rearranged my actions to get around it.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the Action Helper [Context Switch](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.contextswitch.contexts).

You can specify an action context of 'json' for this action and then it will automatically handle disabling the layout and view script rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);` inside action.